# How to respond to _one_ click on a control in a cocoa window that is not key?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview

I have a button in a child window.

If I am working in the parent window (it is key), and I click *once* on the button in the child window, this click makes the child window key. I then have to click a *second* time to make the control (in this case, a button) respond.

How can I immediately respond to a click on that button in a non-key window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is controlled individually for each view class by `-[NSView acceptsFirstMouse:]` which returns `NO` by default. Subclasses have to return `YES` to allow the first click to work.

However, `NSButton` implementation already returns `YES` so it should work as is, unless your button is not painted by `NSButton` instance.

Comment: Ah thank you, I will try this. To be honest, I have a slightly different setup in my windows, but thought that an `NSButton` would simplify things. I guess it was only a source of confusion, sorry!